# Display duration in a human readable format such as "X hours, Y minutes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, intervals, time-format

I am using Rails 4, Ruby 2.1 with PostgreSQL.

I have a database field called `duration` which is an interval data type.

When pulling out the data in this column it returns in the format of `hh:mm:ss`, e.g. `01:30:00`.

I am trying to figure out a way to display this as `1 hour, 30 minutes`.

Other examples:

- `02:00:00` to `2 hours`
- `02:15:00` to `2 hours, 15 minutes`
- `02:01:00` to `2 hours, 1 minute`

Comment: What have you tried to solve this yourself? Note: Stack Overflow is brimming with helpful people who are willing to help *you to write it yourself* (ie we won't do it all for you)... so you need to have a go at writing it yourself first. :)
Have you googled the ruby time-methods? the ruby number-based methods? Do you have a rough idea of what algorithm you might start with? Have a bash and see what you can come up with...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
def duration_of_interval_in_words(interval)
  hours, minutes, seconds = interval.split(':').map(&:to_i)

  [].tap do |parts|
    parts << "#{hours} hour".pluralize(hours)       unless hours.zero?
    parts << "#{minutes} minute".pluralize(minutes) unless minutes.zero?
    parts << "#{seconds} hour".pluralize(seconds)   unless seconds.zero?
  end.join(', ')
end

duration_of_interval_in_words('02:00:00')
# => '2 hours'

duration_of_interval_in_words('02:01:00')
# => '2 hours, 1 minute'

duration_of_interval_in_words('02:15:00')
# => '2 hours, 15 minutes'
```

Answer (score 28):

Just use `duration` + `inspect`

```
seconds = 86400 + 3600 + 15
ActiveSupport::Duration.build(seconds).inspect
=> "1 day, 1 hour, and 15.0 seconds"
```

Or a it can be a little be customized

```
ActiveSupport::Duration.build(seconds).parts.map do |key, value|
  [value.to_i, key].join 
end.join(' ')
=> "1days 1hours 15seconds"
```

P.S.

You can get seconds with

```
1.day.to_i
=> 86400
```

Time can be parsed only in ISO8601 format

```
ActiveSupport::Duration.parse("PT2H15M").inspect
=> "2 hours and 15 minutes"
```

Answer (score 2):

See also
ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper distance_of_time_in_words (and related)

e.g.

```
0 <-> 29 secs # => less than a minute
30 secs <-> 1 min, 29 secs # => 1 minute
1 min, 30 secs <-> 44 mins, 29 secs # => [2..44] minutes
... etc
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words

Perhaps not appropriate to include in a model validation error? (which is my use case)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
irb(main):030:0> def humanized_duration(seconds)
irb(main):031:1>   ActiveSupport::Duration.build(seconds).parts.except(:seconds).reduce("") do |output, (key, val)|
irb(main):032:2*       output+= "#{val}#{key.to_s.first} "
irb(main):033:2>     end.strip
irb(main):034:1>   end
=> :humanized_duration
irb(main):035:0> humanized_duration(920)
=> "15m"
irb(main):036:0> humanized_duration(3920)
=> "1h 5m"
irb(main):037:0> humanized_duration(6920)
=> "1h 55m"
irb(main):038:0> humanized_duration(10800)
=> "3h"
```

You can change the format you want the resulting string to be inside the reduce.  I like the 'h' and 'm' for hours and minutes.   And I excluded the seconds from the duration parts since that wasn't important for my usage of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a locale-aware helper method which builds upon [MasonMc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67294175/766301).

```rb
# app/helpers/date_time_helper.rb
module DateTimeHelper
  def humanized_duration(duration)
    ActiveSupport::Duration.build(duration).parts.except(:seconds).collect do |key, val|
      t(:"datetime.distance_in_words.x_#{key}", count: val)
    end.join(', ')
  end
end
```

You can also replace `join(', ')` with `to_sentence` if it reads better, or get fancy and allow passing a locale, like `distance_of_time_in_words`.

### Gotcha

Rather counter-intuitively, `x_hours` is absent from [Rails' default locale file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml) because [`distance_of_time_in_words`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words) doesn't use it.
You'll need to add it yourself, [even if using the `rails-i18n` gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/pull/673).

```yaml
# config/locales/en.datetime.yml
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      x_hours:
        one: "one hour"
        other: "%{count} hours"
```

Here's the output:

```rb
humanized_duration(100)
# => '1 minute'
humanized_duration(12.34.hours)
# => '12 hours, 20 minutes'
humanized_duration(42.hours)
# => '1 day, 18 hours, 25 minutes'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following method to display such as:

- minutes_to_human(45) # 45 minutes
- minutes_to_human(120) # 2 hours
- minutes_to_human(75) # 2.5 hours
- minutes_to_human(75) # 1.15 hours

---

```
def minutes_to_human(minutes)
  result = {}

  hours = minutes / 60
  result[:hours] = hours if hours.positive?
  result[:minutes] = ((minutes * 60) - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60 if minutes % 60 != 0

  result[:minutes] /= 60.0 if result.key?(:hours) && result.key?(:minutes)

  return I18n.t('helper.minutes_to_human.hours_minutes', time: (result[:hours] + result[:minutes]).round(2)) if result.key?(:hours) && result.key?(:minutes)
  return I18n.t('helper.minutes_to_human.hours', count: result[:hours]) if result.key?(:hours)
  return I18n.t('helper.minutes_to_human.minutes', count: result[:minutes].round) if result.key?(:minutes)
  ''
end
```

---

Translations:

```
en:
  helper:
    minutes_to_human:
      minutes:
        zero: '%{count} minute'
        one: '%{count} minute'
        other: '%{count} minutes'
      hours:
        one: '%{count} hour'
        other: '%{count} hours'
      hours_minutes: '%{time} hours'
```

Answer (score -4):

I find that duration.inspect serve the purpose pretty well.

```
> 10.years.inspect
=> "10 years"
```

Comment: `inspect` method should not be used into views. You should use a proper formatter.

Comment: `10.weeks.inspect` => `"70 days"` and `2.hours.inspect` => `"7200 seconds"`

Comment: `10.weeks.inspect` => `"10 weeks"` and `2.hours.inspect` => `"2 hours"`. It's too bad they can't just copy this inspect to another name, because people wouldn't object to it if it were called anything else, and otherwise seems perfect. Also handles the multiple case nicely: `(1.month + 10.weeks + 2.hours).inspect` => `"1 month, 10 weeks, and 2 hours"`. I mean, I would do it without the last comma, but it's good enough.

Comment: Wow - this is great.  Agree that it deserves to be replicated as something other than .inspect - daft to rewrite something built in that works.  HOWEVER the Oxford Comma is to be respected, this denigration of it will not stand!